# Compiling without (necessary?) #include

Tags: c++, time, include, exit

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

srand(time(0));
double dd [10];
for(int i=0;i!=10; ++i) dd[i]= rand()%5+0;

for(auto i:dd)
cout<<i<<' ';

cout<<endl;

exit(100);

}
```

Why is it compiling without the `#include<ctime>` and `#include<cstdlib>` for the calls to `time(0)` and `exit(100)`(which is absolutely useless there, I know)? Are they already included in `iostream`?

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard, section 17.6.5.2 [res.on.headers], says:

> A C++ header may include other C++ headers.

Which means an implementation is free to include other headers when you include one of them. From an implementor's point of view, that's just quite practical, of course.

There are even headers which are *guaranteed* to include others. For example, `<string>` implies `<initializer_list>`.

As for `<iostream>`, it implies `<ios>` (which itself implies `<iosfwd>`), `<streambuf>`,  `<istream>` and `<ostream>`. So there is no guarantee for `<ctime>` and `<cstdlib>`, and you should include them explicitly for better portability.

To find out which headers are guaranteed to include others, you can either have a look yourself in the standard [or in a draft](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) (see all the synopses starting in section 18), or just go to cppreference.com, for example http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream for `<iostream>`. It's quite a reliable online C++ reference.

Or you just explicitly include *every* header you need. Which may be the best choice in the end.

Comment: *From an implementor's point of view, that's just quite practical* but also dangerous, as code that compiles on one system may not on another or in the future, iff a header that it relies upon is only indirectly included.

Comment: @Walter: But isn't this what I recommend in the last sentence?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I would reword that last sentence a bit as it could be misinterpreted as recommending "always include all headers" as opposed to "always include all *required* headers"

Comment: @user4581301: Indeed. Edited.

Comment: It is, but that sentenct on its own is misleading (and not everybody here reads all sentences in a post).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `iostream` includes `cstdlib` (at least in your case; you should not rely on that dependency chain).
Your compiler might have an option to list the dependencies, e.g. for the GNU C compiler, you can use the `-M` flag to list all includes.